# Google Indexing URL First?

Tags: seo, google, google-search, search-engine-indexing

Does Google index a website's URL link first before the rest of the website? For example, if I search for "FedEx" on Google, is it safe to assume that Google will index "www.fedex.com" and display it first rather than "www.companysite.com/fedex"?

Comment: Do you mean *rank* instead of *index*?

Answer (score 1):

> Does Google index a website's URL link first before the rest of the website?

If, by "website's URL link" you mean the websites "home page" (usually `www.example.com/`) then no, not necessarily. It depends on the page content and how it is being linked to.

> is it safe to assume that Google will index "www.fedex.com" and display it first rather than "www.companysite.com/fedex"

No, not necessarily. It depends on the page content and how it is being linked to.